# Filter array with prefix

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array, of type String:

```
var Arr = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes", "yellow banana", "urban"]
```

How do I filter every word in array that has a prefix of my keyword?
Now I have this:

```
 .filter { $0.contains(keyword) }
 .sorted { ($0.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) }
```

But if I have keyword "ban", it will return "banana", "yellow banana", and "urban".
I need only to filter prefix of every word in array element, to get "banana" and "yellow banana".

Comment: Why do you call sorted() if you only want to filter? What about a simple `.filter { $0.hasPrefix(keyword) }` ?

Comment: @MartinR thanks, but it not helps, in my case, i think i need to split array, by " " seperator, or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression which checks if the keyword 
occurs at a word boundary (`\b` pattern):

```
let array = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes", "yellow banana", "urban"]
let keyword = "ban"

let pattern = "\\b" + NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: keyword)
let filtered = array.filter {
    $0.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil
}

print(filtered) // ["banana", "yellow banana"]
```

And for a case-insensitive search use

```
options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]
```

instead.

Comment: @DavidDavidoff: I double-checked that the above code with `let keyword = "yellow b"` prints `["yellow banana"]` as result. What result do you expect?

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant to send it to another comment.
Only your solution works, with space symbol also, i marked your answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

## Performance Note

I just want to refer to the Time-Complexity caused by filtering the array for matching.

For example :

```
private var words: [String]

func words(matching prefix: String) -> [String]
{
   return words.filter { $0.hasPrefix(prefix) }
}
```

`words(matching:)` will go through the collection of strings and return
the strings that match the prefix.

If the number of elements in the words array is small, this is a
reasonable strategy. But if you’re dealing with more than a few
thousand words, the time it takes to go through the words array will
be **unacceptable**. The **time complexity of words(matching:) is O(k*n)**,
where k is the longest string in the collection, and n is the number of
words you need to check.

**Trie** data structure has excellent performance characteristics for
this type of problem.

Reference : https://www.raywenderlich.com/892-swift-algorithm-club-swift-trie-data-structure

Answer (score 2):

You will need to first break up your string into words using enumerateSubstrings method and then you can check if any of the words contains the keyword prefix:

```
extension String {
    var words: [String] {
        var words: [String] = []
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..<endIndex, options: .byWords) { word,_,_,_ in
            guard let word = word else { return }
            words.append(word)
        }
        return words
    }
}
```

---

```
let arr = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes", "yellow banana", "urban"]
let keyword = "ban"

let filtered = arr.filter { $0.words.contains(where: {$0.hasPrefix(keyword)}) }

filtered // ["banana", "yellow banana"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in **Swift 3+**:

```
let array = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes", "yellow banana", "urban"]
let keyword = "ban"

let filtered = array.filter {
    $0.components(separatedBy: " ").first { $0.hasPrefix(keyword) } != nil
}
print(filtered) // ["banana", "yellow banana"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter array with hasPrefix as follows:

```
// I Use two arrays, actualArray with original data and filteredArray contains data after filtration. You can use whatever is best for your scenario 

  filteredArray =  actaulArray.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(searchBar.text!)  })
```